# Laravel 4 - environment configuration

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am working on a Laravel 4 project and I need to be able to switch between multiple configurations. So as far as I know Laravel enables me to configure envs based on URL like this in the `start.php`

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(

    'local' => array('localhost'),
    'stage' => array('project.stage.com'),
    'prod' => array('project.production.com'),

));
```

And each of this configs consists of separate database connections and other configuration files. What I want is on my local environment to be able to switch between local,stage and prod, so for example if I want to connect to the prod database from my local project to test something. As far as I can understand if I want to do this I need to manualy switch the database connection strings in the local configuration. Is there any other way for switching between configurations on local level ? Hope my question was clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a closure to the function to determine set the environment more dynamically. You can either replicate the logic laravel uses and only use the closure in combination with `gethostname()` or just comment the part out and add this for testing:

```
$app->detectEnvironment(function(){
    return 'stage';
});
```